# Cannot see installation in docker container when using docker-compose

Tags: python, django, apache, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to **dockerize** my **django app** which has PostgreSQL and apache in it. I have my dockerfile and docker-compose.yml and when I run `docker-compose up`, everything works fine. However, when I go into my containers, I cannot see my django, apache vs. But all of my files are copied successfully. I followed the instructions on https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/setting-up-postgresql-database-with-a-django-docker-application/

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code

COPY . /code/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && pip install paramiko && pip install pycrypto
```

and my docker-compose.yml

```
 version:'3'

        services:
           web:
             build: .
             command: python xx/xx/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
             volumes:
              - .:/code
             ports:
              - "8000:8000"
             depends_on:
              - db

           db:
             images: postgres
```

I tried `docker run -it <mycontainer> bash` 
and then try `which python`, `which django` or something and just python is installed. There is no other thing in my container from **requirements.txt**, for example, paramiko or pycrypto. So if my containers do not install them, why docker-compose up is running well?

My requirements.txt

```
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
Django==1.11.13
djangorestframework==3.8.2
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
idna==2.6
numpy==1.14.3
paramiko>=1.15.2
pycrypto==2.6.1
psycopg2==2.7.4
PyJWT==1.6.4
pytz==2018.4
requests==2.18.4
urllib3==1.22
django-rest-swagger==2.2.0
./xx/PyCVESearch
```

My question: why cant I see the things which requirements.txt should download in my container ?

Note: In this dockerfile and docker-compose.yml before from apache. When I saw my containers did not install other things, I gave up to build apache.

Comment: What is output of `pip freeze` inside running django container?

Comment: Can you include the actual `docker run` or `docker-compose` run option you’re using, with the actual image name and any options you’re providing?

Comment: I use just docker-compose build and run, no option

Comment: Does your requirements.txt mention django? Can you show the list of packages?

Comment: Also now I try to dockerize my django on another computer and have this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54216459/newconnectionerror-raise-while-installing-requirements-txt-certifi